# How to calculate the z-scores of factors in multiple columns in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb, z-score

I have a table with a column `trade_date` and multiple factor columns. I would like to standardize these factor columns using the funciton `zscore()`, with *trade-date* as the grouping basis.

How can I pass these columns in batch?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a table `tbl` with columns `trade_date`, `f1`, and `f2`. You can use `update` function to group the table by the `trade_date` column and calculate the z-scores for each factor column using the `zscore()` function. The result includes new columns `f1_zscore` and `f2_zscore` which are standardized values of `f1` and `f2`.

```
update tbl by trade_date, f1_zscore:zscore(f1), f2_zscore:zscore(f2) from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following methods:

**For single column:**

```
select zscore(factor1) from t context by trade_date
```

**For multiple columns:**

(1) in-memory table:

```
contextby(zscore, t, t.trade_date)
```

(2) Otherwise, use meta-programming:

```
t = table(100:0, [`trade_date, `symbol, `f1,`f2,`f3,`f4,`f5], [DATE, SYMBOL, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, DOUBLE])
otherCol = [`trade_date, `symbol]
colName = t.colNames()
factorCol = colName[not colName in otherCol]
sql(select=sqlCol(factorCol, zscore, "re_" + factorCol), from=objByName("t"), groupBy=sqlCol("trade_date"), groupFlag=0)
```